# How to get nth byte from ByteString?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

How can I get nth byte of ByteString in Haskell?

I tried to find function like `!!` for ByteStrings, but found nothing.

Comment: [ByteString.index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:index) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Can you just write answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ByteString.index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:index) is the function you're looking for.

Most of the "containerish" types emulate the extended list interface; you also want to be careful because that `index` function will crash the program if you feed it a string that's too short (as will `!!` on ordinary lists).  A better implementation might be

```
import Data.ByteString as B
nthByte :: Int -> B.ByteString -> Maybe Word8
nthByte n bs = fst <$> B.uncons (B.drop n bs)
```

which, reading inside out, drops the first *n* bytes (maybe producing an empty byte string), then attempts to split the first character from the remainder, and if successful, ignores the rest of the string.